# unmet dependencies: libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.5) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 is installed

Tags: package-management, 64-bit, dependencies, libraries

I really need some fresh idea on this matter, besides a new installation which I'm strongly considering. I don't yet think there's here a related solution and boy how I tried to found and tried many possible solutions. Like

```
apt-get install -f
apt-get update -f
apt-get -f install libc6-amd64 
apt-get install libc6-dev
apt-get install libc6=2.19-0ubuntu6.5 libc6-dev=2.19-0ubuntu6.5
apt-get install libc6=2.19-0ubuntu6.9 libc6-dev=2.19-0ubuntu6.9
apt-cache depends libc6 | grep -Po 'Depends:\s+\K[^ ]+$'
apt-get install --dry-run --reinstall $(apt-cache depends libc6 | grep -Po 'Depends:\s+\K[^ ]+$' | tr '\n'
```

and this solution.

I can't use it since not a thing can be installed, this message keeps showing up:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libc6-dbg:
    Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.5) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 is to be installed
 E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This one as well:

```
[...] depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1)
```

What usually appears as it follows:

```
$ apt-cache depends libc6:amd64 | grep -Po 'Depends:\s+\K[^ ]+$' libgcc1
$ apt-cache depends libgcc1:amd64 | grep -Po 'Depends:\s+\K[^ ]+$'
gcc-4.9-base
libc6
multiarch-support
$ apt-cache depends multiarch-support | grep -Po 'Depends:\s+\K[^ ]+$' libc6
$ sudo apt-get install --dry-run --reinstall $(apt-cache depends libc6:amd64 | grep -Po 'Depends:\s+\K[^ ]+$' | tr '\n' ' ')
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.5) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
$ sudo apt-get install --dry-run --reinstall $(apt-cache depends libc6-dbg:amd64 | grep -Po 'Depends:\s+\K[^ ]+$' | tr '\n' ' ')
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.5) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Your issue is your current sources are only finding an old version of libc6-dbg (2.19-0ubuntu6.5 released 04 Dec 2014) while you've already updated libc6 to the current package (2.19-0ubuntu6.9 released 26 May 2016). These 2 packages must match. So fix your sources, the 1st. answer below probably will

Answer (score 1):

```
 sudo apt-get autoclean
```

remove sources.list file.and create new sources.list...

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

[image]
This will open software-properties-gtk and a newsources.list will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

Tick all the boxes then click on Revert then click close.

Need to restore default repositories

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

(it is good practice to backup this file before installing to recover if such things happen)

Now install anything!

Answer (score 1):

(Temporarily) remove the package `libc6-dbg`:

```
sudo apt-get remove -f libc6-dbg
```

It's not necessary to run anything. You only need it for a more helpful debug output when hunting software bugs.

If you need the package again, you can reinstall it like any other. If there's still a conflict, open a new question and include the output of `apt-cache policy libc6 libc6-dbg`.

Comment: Why would he try to remove a package that's not installed?

Comment: According to the output of `apt-get` included in your question it *half-installed* and missing a dependency. If you want to verify that claim run `dpkg -s libc6-dbg` and look at the `Status` field.